# Can we have a multi-coloured logo as white in the navigation for better visibility?

Tags: website-design, logo

Is it okay to have a white logo on the navigation because of a darker colour shade and the original multicolored logo in the footer? Is this an accepted practice?

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/97255/23061

Comment: Just stumbled across the link after posting the question. Thanks for sharing it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is ok. Having different versions of your logo is more than accepted practice, it's recommended. Large companies will have a **Graphic charter**, which are brand guidelines that details precisely how to use their logo in different situations, for example on a light or dark background, very small or very large, which precise colors to use and much more.

They are usually available online, for example you can find the Twitter guidelines [here](https://about.twitter.com/en_us/company/brand-resources.html).

Comment: Doesn't have to be a large company, they just need to have a good graphic designer 

Comment: That is so true!